# Set custom thumb image on `UISwitch` using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

How to set an image to `UISwitch` programatically?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? You should show the relevant code

Comment: On/Off image was not affecting switch. But I figured it out. On/off image hase no effect on ios 7. [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISwitch/onImage)

Comment: It is a bit confusing because you have applied the tag 'ios8' to the question